# Python string manipulation -- performance problems

Tags: python, string, performance

I have the following piece of code that I execute around 2 million times in my application to parse that many records. This part seems to be the bottleneck and I was wondering if anyone could help me by suggesting some nifty tricks that could make these simple string manipulations faster.

```
try:
    data = []
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for info in self.Columns():
        end = start + (info.columnLength)
        slice = line[start:end]
        if slice == '' or len(slice) != info.columnLength:
            raise 'Wrong Input'
        if info.hasSignage:
            if(slice[0:1].strip() != '+' and slice[0:1].strip() != '-'):
                raise 'Wrong Input'
        if not info.skipColumn:
            data.append(slice)
        start = end 
    parsedLine = data
except:
    parsedLine = False
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is probably better suited for questions like this.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a full, runnable performance test for people to run against.

Comment: String exceptions have been deprecated for many, many years--always raise an `Exception` subclass instead. The only reason they appear to work anymore is that they're wrong and therefore raise an error.

Comment: Bare `except:` is almost always wrong can can lead to frustrating, untrackable bugs. If all you wanted to catch was `raise "Wrong Input"` then what you would do is define `class InvalidInputError(Exception):` `pass` and then `except InvalidInputError:`.

Comment: @Mike Graham: Even better, use `ValueError`, which is the convention for "bad input"

Comment: @Daenyth, That's certainly a common choice, but I do not prefer it myself because it has the potential to catch lots of ValueErrors which aren't the ones I meant to. Because of this type of error, I prefer brand new exceptions as much as possible, *especially* if I have a huge `try` block.

Comment: @Mike Graham: Fair enough. If you're providing a module it's useful to give all your exceptions a common type internal to the module so users can `except MyModuleError` and get all your custom ones :)

Comment: Question for @bbekdeir: will the `self.Columns()` value be the same for each of your millions of records?  Or can each line being parsed have different columns?

Comment: @Mike Graham: even better than a class body of `pass` is a docstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I'm changing this answer a bit.  I'll leave the original answer below.

In my other answer I commented that the best thing would be to find a built-in Python module that would do the unpacking.  I couldn't think of one, but perhaps I should have Google searched for one.  @John Machin provided an answer that showed how to do it: use the Python `struct` module.  Since that is written in C, it should be faster than my pure Python solution.  (I haven't actually measured anything so it is a guess.)

I do agree that the logic in the original code is "un-Pythonic".  Returning a sentinel value isn't best; it's better to either return a valid value or raise an exception.  The other way to do it is to return a list of valid values, plus another list of invalid values.  Since @John Machin offered code to yield up valid values, I thought I'd write a version here that returns two lists.

NOTE: Perhaps the best possible answer would be to take @John Machin's answer and modify it to save the invalid values to a file for possible later review.  His answer yields up answers one at a time, so there is no need to build a large list of parsed records; and saving the bad lines to disk means there is no need to build a possibly-large list of bad lines.

```
import struct

def parse_records(self):
    """
    returns a tuple: (good, bad)
    good is a list of valid records (as tuples)
    bad is a list of tuples: (line_num, line, err)
    """

    cols = self.Columns()
    unpack_fmt = ""
    sign_checks = []
    start = 0
    for colx, info in enumerate(cols, 1):
        clen = info.columnLength
        if clen < 1:
            raise ValueError("Column %d: Bad columnLength %r" % (colx, clen))
        if info.skipColumn:
            unpack_fmt += str(clen) + "x"
        else:
            unpack_fmt += str(clen) + "s"
            if info.hasSignage:
                sign_checks.append(start)
        start += clen
    expected_len = start
    unpack = struct.Struct(unpack_fmt).unpack

    good = []
    bad = []
    for line_num, line in enumerate(self.whatever_the_list_of_lines_is, 1):
        if len(line) != expected_len:
            bad.append((line_num, line, "bad length"))
            continue
        if not all(line[i] in '+-' for i in sign_checks):
            bad.append((line_num, line, "sign check failed"))
            continue
        good.append(unpack(line))

    return good, bad
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER TEXT:
This answer should be a lot faster if the `self.Columns()` information is identical over all the records.  We do the processing of the `self.Columns()` information one time, and build a couple of lists that contain just what we need to process a record.

This code shows how to compute `parsedList` but doesn't actually yield it up or return it or do anything with it.  Obviously you would need to change that.

```
def parse_records(self):
    cols = self.Columns()

    slices = []
    sign_checks = []
    start = 0
    for info in cols:
        if info.columnLength < 1:
            raise ValueError, "bad columnLength"
        end = start + info.columnLength
        if not info.skipColumn:
            tup = (start, end)
            slices.append(tup)   
            if info.hasSignage:
                sign_checks.append(start)

    expected_len = end # or use (end - 1) to not count a newline

    try:
        for line in self.whatever_the_list_of_lines_is:
            if len(line) != expected_len:
                raise ValueError, "wrong length"
            if not all(line[i] in '+-' for i in sign_checks):
                raise ValueError, "wrong input"
            parsedLine = [line[s:e] for s, e in slices]

    except ValueError:
        parsedLine = False
```

Comment: That's what I meant in my commentary edits, very nice, and 'info.hasSignage' must be indented 4 spaces. bbekdemir is having a Royal treatment on his first post...

Comment: And thanks everyone for your responses - especially @steveha. I am amazed by how quickly I got answers.

Comment: @Remi, I edited the code to indent as you suggested, on the assumption that if we are skipping the column, we don't need to check the sign.  Without the indent, we check every sign whether skipping that column or not; that might actually be desired.

Comment: This would be made more efficient by using (a) `for..else` rather than `try..except`, or (b) `parsedLine = None; break` instead of `raise` and throw away the `try..except` wrapping.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: the exceptions in Python are slow if they are frequently taken, and fast if they are not taken.  If the exceptions are rare, this code will be fast.

Comment: @John Machin:  While I wouldn't have written this code the way it was done by @bbekdemir, I don't think "smelly bits" is a useful criticism.  As I said in my other answer, I like how you can debug this just by changing the `try`/`except` to not catch the exceptions anymore, if you want to find where the input was bad.  And hey presto, if you do that, the different exception messages are in fact seen.

Comment: @John Machin: As sentinel values go, `False` is OK for an error.  I thought about changing the code to return `[]` on error, but code trying to index into a zero-length list will still fail with an exception.  In either case you need to do `if data:` or catch an exception to handle the error.  If you don't like this code, it would be more helpful for you to rewrite it and show us all how it is properly done; a better example is much more persuasive than snide comments.  I think this code would be better if it just raised an exception on error without catching it; is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @steveha: `False` is NOT OK for an error return. It would necessitate `if returned_value == False:` -- enough to get one thrown unceremoniously out of a job interview. Note that `[]` is a non-error return -- it indicates that `cols` was empty or that all columns were skipped. You seem to be gradually approaching enlightenment: Scrape off the evil try/except, and include the relevant variable info in the exception message. When would you not want to find where the input was bad?? See my updated answer.

Comment: @John Machin, you seem determined to be as insulting as possible.  Are you like this every day, or is it just today?  It seems likely that any valid record will evaluate true, so just `if returned_value:` would suffice.  When I answered his question, I left his original logic mostly intact.  However, I agree that it is more Pythonic to just return valid data, and raise an exception on errors.  Or, alternatively, return two lists, the valid list and the bad list.  I'm going to edit my answer a bit now.

Comment: @steveha: You seem to be determined to be insulted; not much that I can do about that. You have missed the point that a valid return includes `[]`, which evaluates to false. The OP has 2 million lines, and you want to return lists??

Comment: @John Machin: It's not my job to teach you manners, so never mind; insult me, patronize me, whatever.  Once you actually posted an answer it was indeed better than mine, as I already noted; good for you, and thank you for teaching me something.  The return of `False` was in the original code, and I just didn't change it at first; it seems to be working for him, just too slowly, so in practice `[]` seems not an issue.  As for a list with two million things in it: it depends on how big the things are, and how much memory he has; it might be fine, or not.  You already did the `yield` answer.

Comment: I just added a note, suggesting that perhaps the best answer would be to take the @John Machin answer and modify it to write bad input lines to a file while yielding up the successfully parsed records.  That would allow for parsing all input records even in the face of errors, and wouldn't require large lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
def fubarise(data):
    try:
        if nasty(data):
            raise ValueError("Look, Ma, I'm doing a big fat GOTO ...") # sheesh #1
        more_of_the_same()
        parsed_line = data
    except ValueError:
        parsed_line = False
        # so it can be a "data" or False -- sheesh #2
    return parsed_line
```

There is no point in having different error messages in the `raise` statement; they are never seen. Sheesh #3.

**Update:** Here is a suggested improvement which uses `struct.unpack` to partition input lines rapidly. It also illustrates better exception handling, under the assumption that the writer of the code is also running it and stopping on the first error is acceptable. A robust implementation which logs all errors in all columns of all lines for a user audience is another matter. Note that typically the error checking for each column would be much more extensive e.g. checking for a leading sign but not checking whether the column contains a valid number seems a little odd.

```
import struct

def unpacked_records(self):
    cols = self.Columns()
    unpack_fmt = ""
    sign_checks = []
    start = 0
    for colx, info in enumerate(cols, 1):
        clen = info.columnLength
        if clen < 1:
            raise ValueError("Column %d: Bad columnLength %r" % (colx, clen))
        if info.skipColumn:
            unpack_fmt += str(clen) + "x"
        else:
            unpack_fmt += str(clen) + "s"
            if info.hasSignage:
                sign_checks.append(start)
        start += clen
    expected_len = start
    unpack = struct.Struct(unpack_fmt).unpack

    for linex, line in enumerate(self.whatever_the_list_of_lines_is, 1):
        if len(line) != expected_len:
            raise ValueError(
                "Line %d: Actual length %d, expected %d"
                % (linex, len(line), expected_len))
        if not all(line[i] in '+-' for i in sign_checks):
            raise ValueError("Line %d: At least one column fails sign check" % linex)
        yield unpack(line) # a tuple
```

Comment: Wow, you really found ways to make your points in obnoxious ways.  Is that how you make friends and influence people?  This isn't an answer to his question at all, just a critique of his coding style, and made rather insulting just to minimize the chances he will actually pay attention to you.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering his question.  Because you are using a builtin module, this should be faster than my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

what about (using some classes to have an executable example):

```
class Info(object):
    columnLength = 5
    hasSignage = True
    skipColumn = False

class Something(object):

    def Columns(self):
        return [Info()]*4

    def bottleneck(self):
        try:
            data = []
            start = 0
            end = 0
            line = '+this-is just a line for testing'
            for info in self.Columns():
                start = end
                collength = info.columnLength
                end = start + collength
                if info.skipColumn:  # start with this
                    continue

                elif collength == 0: 
                    raise ValueError('Wrong Input')

                slice = line[start:end] # only now slicing, because it
                                        # is probably most expensive part

                if len(slice) != collength: 
                    raise ValueError('Wrong Input')

                elif info.hasSignage and slice[0] not in '+-': # bit more compact
                    raise ValueError('Wrong Input')

                else:
                    data.append(slice)

            parsedLine = data
        except:
            parsedLine = False

Something().bottleneck()
```

edit:
 when length of slice is 0, slice[0] does not exist, so `if collength == 0` has to be checked for first

edit2:
 You are using this bit of code for many many lines, but the column info does not change, right? That allows you, to

- pre-calculate a list of start points of each colum (no more need to calculate start, end)
- knowing start-end in advance, .Columns() only needs to return columns that are not skipped and have a columnlength >0 (or do you really need to raise an input for length==0 at each line??)
- the manditory length of each line is known and equal or each line and can be checked before looping over the column infos

edit3:
I wonder how you will know what data index belongs to which column if you use 'skipColumn'...

Comment: +1, I was in the process of suggesting moving the skipColumn check up and simplifying the signage check myself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compute  `start` and `end` every time through this loop.

Compute them exactly once prior to using `self.Columns()` (Whatever that is.  If 'Columns` is class with static values, that's silly.  If it's a function with a name that begins with a capital letter, that's confusing.)

`if slice == '' or len(slice) != info.columnLength` can only happen if line is too short compared to the total size required by `Columns`.  Check once, outside the loop.

`slice[0:1].strip() != '+'` sure looks like `.startswith()`.

`if not info.skipColumn`.  Apply this filter before even starting the loop.  Remove these from `self.Columns()`.

Comment: Sorry, don't agree about `start` and `end`.  Those are being used to take a different slice out of the input string each time; they depend on `info.columnLength`.  Also, the check of `info.columnLength` makes sense if you are worried about possible garbage `.columnLength` values; I think the correction there is to try to handle it with an exception rather than inline code (ETAFTGP).  Completely agree about `.startswith()`; and `.startswith()` should be called with a tuple argument of `('+', '-')`.

Comment: But wait... he says he is processing many lines at a time, and it's possible that the `self.Columns()` value is constant over all the lines.  In which case, we could save a lot of time by precomputing a set of `(start, end)` tuples.  If that is what you meant, I withdraw my disagreement.

Comment: @steveha: "and it's possible that the self.Columns() value is constant over all the lines".  Not "possible".  Generally, it's essential.  That's what fixed -- positional -- file formats depend on.  Fixed positions in each row.

Comment: I started off just looking at what the code is actually doing, and making no assumptions otherwise.  Tunnel vision on the code itself.  Then I took a step back and said, "hmm, he says he is processing records."

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would consider is `slice = line[start:end]`. Slicing creates new instances; you could try to avoid explicitly constructing `line [start:end]` and examine its contents manually.

Why are you doing `slice[0:1]`? This should yield a subsequence containing a single item of `slice` (shouldn't it?), thus it can probably be checked more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you to use some sort of built-in Python feature to split the string, but I can't think of one.  So I'm left with just trying to reduce the amount of code you have.

When we are done, `end` should be pointing at the end of the string; if this is the case, then all of the `.columnLength` values must have been okay.  (Unless one was negative or something!)

Since this has a reference to `self` it must be a snip from a member function.  So, instead of raising exceptions, you could just `return False` to exit the function early and return an error flag.  But I like the debugging potential of changing the `except` clause to not catch the exception anymore, and getting a stack trace letting you identify where the problem came from.

@Remi used `slice[0] in '+-'` where I used `slice.startswith(('+', '-))`.  I think I like @Remi's code better there, but I left mine unchanged just to show you a different way.  The `.startswith()` way will work for strings longer than length 1, but since this is only a string of length 1 the terse solution works.

```
try:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    data = []
    start = 0
    for info in self.Columns():
        end = start + info.columnLength
        slice = line[start:end]
        if info.hasSignage and not slice.startswith(('+', '-')):
            raise ValueError, "wrong input"
        if not info.skipColumn:
            data.append(slice)
        start = end

    if end - 1 != len(line):
        raise ValueError, "bad .columnLength"

    parsedLine = data

except ValueError:
    parsedLine = False
```